# how to wait for a non-child process with winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I read:

- [How to wait for a process to finish C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454019/how-to-wait-for-a-process-to-finish-c)
- [How to use win32 CreateProcess function to wait until the child done to write to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907917/how-to-use-win32-createprocess-function-to-wait-until-the-child-done-to-write-to)

Code snippet:

```
HANDLE  hProcess = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, TRUE, inProcessID); 

if (NULL == hProcess)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hProcess,INFINITE);
}
```

I've tried `WaitForSingleObject` and `WaitForSingleObjectEx`, neither are actually waiting.

For example assume notepad is running and I want to wait for it to be closed by some user. What shall I do ?

Comment: The code you provided looks correct (assuming you're opening the correct process via `OpenProcess`, and getting a valid `HANDLE`). What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: When you look at `WaitForSingleObject` online document, it has a list shows all objects can be waited, which does not include Snapshot....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation for `OpenProcess`:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is an open handle to the
>   specified process.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error
>   information, call GetLastError.

So your if statement should be:

```
if (NULL != hProcess) ...
```